# The icon is not getting loaded

Tags: html, utf

The icon for sidebar which is `content: "\f20e";` is not getting displayed, not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you use a certain library to call those icons? (e.g fontawesome)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Without more information, we can only guess at what's going on here. Please include code snippets of the relevant html & css; and tell us which font library you're using.

Comment: i have used http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css. I want ion-navicon class to be used. `<a className="ion-navicon"></a>`.